# Want to get string character by character

Tags: string

Using Android when I write this code, I am presented with the error at `str[i]` "Array type expected"..

```
   String str=ex.getText().toString();
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
    {
       if(str[i]=='a')
       {
          tx.setText("A");
       }
    }
```

now how i can get String 'str' character by character...

Comment: Down-votes on every supplied answer without any comments or edits that would help us, or anyone else, figure out why those answers are not correct.  You haven't supplied a language that you're working in, which is key to providing you with the correct method and syntax.

Comment: He said using Android so you can infer from that either Java or C# from his code, and my code works in both. @Draco18s

Comment: @apkisbossin I assumed Java because it looks like Java and he said he's working on the Android platform.  But that still doesn't explain the downvoted answers.

Comment: Yea @Draco18s, I was wondering why I got a downvote

Answer (score 0):

You said "Android" so I'm assuming you're coding in Java.  In which case:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_charat.htm

Answer (score -1):

You could do

```
char[] charbychar = ex.getText().toString().toCharArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to access a string by index. Your str is string, not an array.

You could do something like this

```
char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
```

to do what you are trying to in your if-statement. Hope it helps.